# Using OpenLayers and OpenStreetMaps to display statistical information with colors?

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap

I'm planning to build a statistical tool using OpenLayers and OpenStreetMaps. This tool will have to display statistical data for French departments with colors. What I would like to do is the same as this :

http://sd1878.sivit.org/geoclip_stats_o3/index.php?profil=FR#v=map3;i=ocs.p_c1_2006;l=fr;z=178717,7038714,864706,751147

Does OpenLayers/OpenStreetMaps allow this ? Or should I look for other alternatives ?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit uncertain, because it isn't clear what format you already have the data in. However OpenLayers can show the data in many formats, and you could choose to render the data as vector or raster, or a combination.

A combination is provided as one of the OpenLayers examples (using United States data, but the translation should not be too hard) - see [WFS: United States](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wfs-states.html). Note that the source code is provided in a link at the bottom.

You might like to review [the many OpenLayers examples](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/) if that doesn't meet your precise needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My data is in JSON format with the department's name as key and misc data as value that will be displayed in a popup when the mouse is on top of the department.
I suppose I will have to draw polygons for each department, which means that I will have to find all departments coordinates ?

Comment: I think that might be another question.